# identifying the coldfusion value comng to run against query

Tags: coldfusion

I am passing dynamically named parameters in the url. (The number of sSearch parameters can go beyond 5 to 7 or 8 etc)

```
sSearch_0   
sSearch_1   
sSearch_2   
sSearch_3   
sSearch_4   
sSearch_5
```

I want to run a loop to do a search within a query. I am trying like this:

```
<cfloop from="0" to="5" index="k">
<cfset counter = k>
    <cfif IsDefined('url.sSearch_' & counter)>
        <cfset "check_" & k = 'url.sSearch_' & counter>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

I am trying to write in a query like this:

```
<cfquery datasource="#coldfusionDatasource#" name="qFiltered">
    SELECT * 
    FROM    mytable 
    <cfif len(trim(url.sSearch))>
        WHERE 
        <cfloop list="#listColumns#" index="thisColumn">
           <cfif thisColumn neq listFirst(listColumns)> OR </cfif>
            #thisColumn# LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" 
                                   value="%#trim(url.sSearch)#%" />
        </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

But it is not working. The error says check_ is undefined.

Comment: `url.sSearch` is not the same as any of the `url.sSearch_' & counter fields

Comment: Since you are talking about url variables, looping through the cgi.query_string might simplify matters somewhat.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to develop an Cold Fusion api for remote requests by DataTables plugin?

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic variable naming using quotes, try:

```
<cfset "check_#k#" = 'url.sSearch_' & counter>
```

See [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/152-dynamic-coldfusion-variables-via-quoted-naming.htm)